# ngSwitchCase in angular 2 instead of ngSwitchWhen

Tags: angular, ng-switch

I was using ngSwitchWhen & now I want to use ngSwitchCase, I referred to the syntax here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html & did the same in my application. There aren't any errors but it isn't working fine either. Somehow the plunker available in the above link for the example provided uses ngSwitchWhen.
Here's my sub.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'subjects',
    templateUrl: 'app/subjects.component.html' ,
    styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
    directives:[MdButton,MdCard,MdToolbar,MdIcon,MdInput,MD_INPUT_DIRECTIVES,MdCheckbox,ProfileDetailsComponent,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
     providers:[MdIconRegistry]
})

export class SubjectsComponent{
    viewMode='first';
    view='one';
    stateNext: boolean = false;

  private buttonState: boolean = true;

  private classes1 = [{label: 'English', state: false},{label:  'Hindi', state: false},{label:  'Mathematics', state: false},{label:  'Science', state: false},{label:  'Computer Science', state: false},{label:  'Social science', state: false},{label:  'Environmental Studies', state: false}];
  private classes6 = [{label: 'English', state: false},{label:  'Hindi', state: false},{label:  'Mathematics', state: false}];
  private classes9 = [{label: 'English', state: false},{label:  'Hindi', state: false},{label:  'Mathematics', state: false}];
  private classes11 =[{label: 'English', state: false},{label:  'Hindi', state: false},{label:  'Mathematics', state: false}];
  private classes12 =  [{label:  'Sanskrit', state: false},{label: 'Accounts', state: false},{label:  'Biology', state: false}];



  setButtonState() {
    let counter = 0;
    for(let i=0;i<this.classes1.length;i++) {
          if (this.classes1[i].state === true) {
             counter++;
          }}

      if (counter >= 1) { this.buttonState = false; }
      else {this.buttonState = true;}
  }
    setButtonState1() {
    let counter = 0;
    for(let i=0;i<this.classes6.length;i++) {
          if (this.classes6[i].state === true) {
             counter++;
          }}

      if (counter >= 1) { this.buttonState = false; }
      else {this.buttonState = true;}
  }
    setButtonState2() {
    let counter = 0;
    for(let i=0;i<this.classes9.length;i++) {
          if (this.classes9[i].state === true) {
             counter++;
          }}

      if (counter >= 1) { this.buttonState = false; }
      else {this.buttonState = true;}
  }
    setButtonState3() {
    let counter = 0;
    for(let i=0;i<this.classes11.length;i++) {
          if (this.classes11[i].state === true) {
             counter++;
          }}

      if (counter >= 1) { this.buttonState = false; }
      else {this.buttonState = true;}
  }
}
```

Here's my sub.compnent.html:

```
<div style="margin-top:16px;">
    <div class="scroll">
<ul style="list-style: none;">
                <li style="margin-left:-50px;" ><md-card class="new" style="height:60px; width:200px;margin-left: 31px;margin-top:4px; border-top: 4px solid #5171C3;" (click)="view='one'">
                    <h5  class="class">Class 1 to 5</h5>
                </md-card></li>

                <li style="margin-left:-50px;"><md-card class="new" style="height:60px; width:200px;margin-left: 31px;margin-top:22px; border-top: 4px solid #2EA83B;" (click)="view='two'">
                  <h5 class="class">Class 6 to 8</h5>
                </md-card></li>

                <li style="margin-left:-50px;" ><md-card class="new" style="height:60px;width:200px;margin-left: 31px;margin-top:22px; border-top: 4px solid #BDB235;" (click)="view='three'">
                    <h5 class="class">Class 9 to 10</h5>
                </md-card></li>

                <li style="margin-left:-50px;" ><md-card class="new" style="height:60px; width:200px;margin-left: 31px;margin-top:22px; border-top: 4px solid #DE660F;" (click)="view='four'">
                    <h5 class="class">Class 11 to 12</h5>
                </md-card></li>
</ul>
</div>

    <div [ngSwitch]="view" >


        <template [ngSwitchCase]="two">
             <md-card style="height:307px; width:243px;margin-left: 251px;margin-top: -308px;background-color:white;">
            <div style="background-color:#2EA83B;height:124px;width:243px;"></div>
            <div style="padding-top:36px;"> <label *ngFor="let cb of  classes6" style="font-size:14px;padding-left:12px;">
 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cb.state" (ngModelChange)="setButtonState1()" class="checkbox" checked/>{{cb.label}}<br/>
</label></div>
            </md-card>
        </template>

        <template [ngSwitchCase]="three">
            <md-card style="height:307px; width:243px;margin-left: 251px;margin-top: -308px;background-color:white;">
            <div style="background-color:#BDB235;height:124px;width:243px;"></div>
            <div style="padding-top:36px;"> <label *ngFor="let cb of  classes9" style="font-size:14px;padding-left:12px;">
 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cb.state" (ngModelChange)="setButtonState2()" class="checkbox" checked/>{{cb.label}}<br/>
</label></div>
            </md-card>
        </template>

        <template [ngSwitchCase]="four">
            <md-card style="height:307px; width:243px;margin-left: 251px;margin-top: -308px;background-color:white;">
            <div style="background-color:#DE660F;height:124px;width:243px;"></div>
            <div style="padding-top:0px;">
            <table style="margin-top: -38px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:54px;">
                        <label *ngFor="let cb of  classes11" style="font-size:14px;padding-left:6px;">
 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cb.state" (ngModelChange)="setButtonState3()" class="checkbox" checked/>{{cb.label}}<br/>
</label></td>
                    <td style="padding-left:10px;padding-top:54px;">
                        <label *ngFor="let cb of  classes12" style="font-size:14px;padding-left:6px;">
 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cb.state" (ngModelChange)="setButtonState3()" class="checkbox" checked/>{{cb.label}}<br/>
</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            </md-card>
        </template>

                <template ngSwitchDefault="one">
            <md-card style="height:307px; width:243px;margin-left: 251px;margin-top: -308px;background-color:white;">
        <div style="background-color:#5171C3;height:124px;width:243px;"></div>
         <div style="padding-top:36px;">   <label *ngFor="let cb of  classes1" style="font-size:14px;padding-left:12px;">
 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cb.state" (ngModelChange)="setButtonState()" class="checkbox" checked/>{{cb.label}}<br/>
</label></div>
            </md-card>
        </template>
    </div>

</div>
```

No matter which ever option I click, I am getting the html of ngSwitchDefault

Comment: What Angular2 version?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I hope you're asking for this "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.6"

Comment: I don't know how angular-cli versions are related to Angular2 versions. For me the Angular2 version would be interesting.

Comment: How do I find the angular2 version...? I tried angular.version & angular.version.full on console, didn't help

Comment: Does your systemjs config contain a version constraint?

Comment: I could only find system-config.js & it doesn't seem to have a version constraint :(

Comment: Than it's probably the most recent version RC.4. I don't use TS locally (only Dart) and don't know much about how to configure projects.

Comment: What is `four` in `[ngSwitchCase]="four"`?

Comment: Yes maybe beacause I found this in package.json :  "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4", any idea why is the switch not working..?

Comment: On the left side is a list of four cards, & on the right side there's just one card, on clicking the cards on the left side the content of the right card would change, so view="four" has the content for the fourth card

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess what you want is

```
<template ngSwitchCase="four">
```

instead of `<template [ngSwitchCase]="four">`

or alternatively

```
<template [ngSwitchCase]="'four'">
```

This code

```
<template [ngSwitchCase]="four">
```

looks up the value of the property `four` but I assume what you want is the string `"four"`

Comment: Thanks a lot again, <template ngSwitchCase="four"> is working fine! :D Even I was using <template [ngSwitchWhen]="'two'"> with ngSwitchWhen, it somehow didn't work right with ngSwitchCase(may have been some other error)

Comment: When the page loads initially there's no card on the right side & I want the content of the first card on the right side even after putting it in ngSwitchdefault I dont get it, any idea why ?

Comment: Actually I can't make any sense of your comments. Have you checked my answer? Is `four` a property or a string?

Comment: It is  a string, & I want the content of view="one" to be present when nothing is clicked or selected

Comment: Please try to reproduce in a Plunker (as simple as possible with everything removed that is not necessary like styles)

Comment: & yes I checked your answer & it worked fine, I was asking an additional thing :)

Comment: I would expect it to work. `ngSwitchDefault` doesn't take a value but setting one shouldn't hurt.

Comment: somehow it is working fine on plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/FOJHofLSgLRB4Po5Li6B?p=preview the checkboxes for first option are present there when the page loads, but not in my application

Comment: Sorry, no idea. If it works in the Plunker then the code is probably correct. Maybe some timing issue? Do you have async calls in your app that you don't have in Plunker? I can't open the Plunker right now, there seems to be an issue with the Plunker site.

Comment: Not sure about what an asynchronous call is, but I am using router directives, thanks a lot anyway, I'll look into it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117715/discussion-between-himanshi-gupta-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Async is usually `http.get(...)` or anything with `subscribe(...)` or `then(...)`